# How to count empty input text fields amount?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to count empty input text fields amount..

i have written this code to count empty fields. this works fine on fields with pre-loaded value. but after i type something in other text fields and try the function again it gives the same result of "2". it seems function is neglecting the values which have added after the loading.

how can i improve this to work fine with even after typing texts in fields after the html is loaded?

*i searched on stack and found no good answers for this question.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".pool", function() {
            
        var count = $('.option[value=""]').length;
        alert(count);
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="optionlist">
  
  <input type="text" class="option form-control"  value="bla bla">
  <input type="text" class="option form-control"  value="">
  <input type="text" class="option form-control"  value="">
           
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", ".pool", function() {
    var count=0;
    $(".option").each(function(){
        count = count+($.trim($(this).val())=="" ? 1 : 0);
    });
    alert(count);
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcr6xn3e/2/)

Comment: Side note: `return !$(this).val()` would suffice.

Comment: Thanks @brijesh. this grate. working!

Comment: @user3818511 your wc..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a filter that checks the .val() for empty string.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".pool", function() {
            
        var count = $('.option:text').filter(function(input){
            return $(this).val() == "";
        }).length;

        alert(count);
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="optionlist">
  
  <input type="text" class="option form-control"  value="bla bla">
  <input type="text" class="option form-control"  value="">
  <input type="text" class="option form-control"  value="">
  <input type="button" value="Click" class="pool" />
           
</div>
```

Comment: Side note: `return !$(this).val()` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$(document).on("click", ".pool", function() {

    var count = 0;
    $('.option').each(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
            count++;
        }
    })
    alert(count);

});
```

Comment: Side note: `return !$(this).val()` would suffice.